# Could not parse error on rally for query using FormattedID

Tags: php, rest, rally

I am using the PHP Toolkit for Rally REST API from here:
github.com/RallyTools github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForPHP

When I use,

```
    $result = $this->find('defect', '(Name = "'. $issueID . '")');
```

this works fine without any error logs.

But when I use,

```
    $result = $this->find('defect', '(FormattedID = "'. $issueID . '")');
```

I am receiving **Could not parse ""** error. Can anyone please help me with this?

EDIT: Hi, I found out what was wrong. This had nothing to do with FormattedID. The results of the query were correct, but the function expects a simpleXMLElement, while I was passing a string array as below. Now, I am stuck at how to convert the array below to simpleXMLElement. Pls help!

EDIT AGAIN: I solved my problem by parsing through the array itself instead of converting it to simpleXMLElement.

Comment: You always want to check what `$issueID` contains with `var_dump()`.

Comment: The value of $issueID is whatever I hardcode. For the same value of the variable $issueID, I am getting a parse error for FormattedID but no error for Name even though no values are returned. For example, $ issueID = DE1234

Comment: Is that a PHP error ? Can you post the full error message ?

Answer (score 0):

Used array instead of SimpleXMLElement.